# Получение поста и вывод его содержимого (WordPress REST API)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, rest

Не могу адекватно вывести пост у себя на странице, опираясь на **REST API**.

Есть сайт на локальном хостинге.
Есть следующий код со страницы:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function getPost({ posts: serverPost }) {
  const [posts, setPost] = useState(serverPost)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      const response = await fetch('http://uer/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
      const result = await response.json()
      setPost(result)
    }

    if (!serverPost) load()
  }, [])

  if (!posts)
    return <h1>loading</h1>

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {posts[0].content.rendered}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

getPost.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  if (!req) {
    return { posts: null }
  }
  const response = await fetch('http://uer/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
  const posts = await response.json()

  return posts
}

export default getPost
```

Он работает и работает хорошо, только дело в том, что в ***posts[0].content.rendered*** хранится текст поста сразу вместе с HTML-тэгами и на страницу выводится он тоже с тэгами.

Как мне в JSX вывести данных текст без тэгов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Преобразовал полученные данные из строки в JSX, фрагмент кода:

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: posts[0].content.rendered}} />      
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

Преобразование из строки в JSX подсмотрел [здесь](https://overcoder.net/q/40120/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-jsx):